# nsstring value results into null in objective c?

Tags: iphone

I am having very nominal yet awkward problem. I am having one textfield in one page and i m passing the value of the same from that page to another page's nsstring variable. Say i m having two pages with objects name A and B. Now when i write A.str = txtfield.text,then i can see the value of the string variable in the colsole,but on the next page,the fetched value is NULL.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you passing A to the next view? Could we see some actual code?

Comment: A is second view object or first view object? If it is a second view object then it will work

Comment: This is not sufficient information.give snippet of code where you set the str and get the value of str also .h code for both classes.

Comment: ya,but i took help of the below code,and got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use singleton object to do so, I think you are not following that.

Simply use appDelegate to transfer the string between two views.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standart NSUserDefaults class.
In first view you put data into user defaults:

```
NSString *yourData = @"yourData";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:yourData forKey:@"userInfoKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

In second you get them:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *yourData = [defaults objectForKey:@"userInfoKey"];
```

Note that you can put any NSObject type of your data, not only NSString.

Comment: hey..thank you so much,i tried both of the codes,it works finely.